# How to initialize a pointer to an array in a class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, templates

I have this code

```
template <class ItemType>
class ArrTest {
public:
    ArrTest();
private:
    ItemType* info;
};

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest()
{
    info = ItemType[50];
}

int main() {
    ArrTest<int> ar();
    return 0;
}
```

Right now when I try and build this I get

```
../src/test1.cpp:23:9: error: 'ItemType' does not refer to a value
        info = ItemType[50];
```

I don't understand how to initialize this into pointer. I believe its a pointer to the first item in the array. but then I should also be able to do info[3] for the 4th member of the array for instance.

Comment: `info = new ItemType[50]`, then you will need a destructor to `delete[]` it. If the size is always 50, and never changing, then define the array as simply `ItemType info[50]` Generally, avoid use of raw pointers in C++

Comment: Also note that `ArrTest<int> ar();` uses [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Instead of having `ItemType* info;` and using `info = new ItemType[50]`, you should use a `std::vector<ItemType>` instead.

Comment: What do you think `info = ItemType[50];` does? What do you think `info` points to after the constructor returns?

Comment: @AnoopRana -- `ArrTest<int> ar();` is **not** the "most vexing parse". It's just a function declaration. It's certainly vexing for beginners, but, as the page you linked to indicates, the "most vexing parse" is more convoluted.

Comment: @PeteBecker I thought that was the point. Rather than being a declaration for an automatic variable, it is a forward declaration of a function. Commonly referred toas the "most vexing parse". It was the whole point of adding `{}` to the initializer to avoid this parsing issue. `ArrTest<int> ar{};`

Comment: @PeteBecker [What is the most vexing parse?](https://www.sandordargo.com/blog/2021/12/22/most-vexing-parse) "*[The most vexing parse] is formally defined in section 8.2 of the C++ language standard. It means that whatever that can be interpreted as a function declaration will be interpreted as a function declaration... Take the following example: `std::string foo();` Probably **this is the simplest form of the most vexing parse**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- yes, there are sources that claim that a function prototype with no arguments is the most vexing parse. The **examples** on the Wikipedia page that Anoop cited don't include that simple prototype, and, if I remember correctly, Scott Myers, who coined the term, didn't see that simple prototype as "most vexing". In the context of `int x();` it's meaning is clear, except to beginners. It's more complex cases, like `void f(double my_dbl) { int i(int(my_dbl)); }`, that really warrant being called **most** vexing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- perhaps a simpler explanation is that with `int f()`, once you've learned about how it's parsed, it's something you intentionally write to express a particular notion. The more complex examples are things you would decide **not** to write, because they are too confusing. Hence, **most** vexing parse is something to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `new[]` operator to allocate the array dynamically:

```cpp
template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest()
    : info(new ItemType[50])
{
}
```

And then, be sure to add a destructor to `delete[]`'s the array, and also add copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

```cpp
template <class ItemType>
class ArrTest {
public:
    ArrTest();
    ArrTest(const ArrTest &src);
    ArrTest(ArrTest &&src);
    ~ArrTest();
    ArrTest& operator=(ArrTest src);
private:
    ItemType* info;
};

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest()
    : info(new ItemType[50])
{
}

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest(const ArrTest &src)
    : info(new ItemType[50])
{
    std::copy(src.info, src.info + 50, info);
}

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest(ArrTest &&src)
    : info(nullptr)
{
    std::swap(info, src.info);
}

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::~ArrTest()
{
    delete[] info;
}

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>& ArrTest<ItemType>::operator=(ArrTest<ItemType> src)
{
    std::swap(info, src.info);
    return *this;
}
```

A better solution would be to use `std::vector` instead, and let it handle all of these details for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <class ItemType>
class ArrTest {
public:
    ArrTest();
private:
    std::vector<ItemType> info;
};

template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest()
    : info(50)
{
}
```

---

Either way, `ArrTest<int> ar();` *does not* declare a default-constructed variable named `ar` of type `ArrTest<int>`, like you are expecting.  It declares a function named `ar` that takes no parameters and returns an `ArrTest<int>`, which is not what you want.

To avoid that, you need to either:

- drop the parenthesis:

  `ArrTest<int> ar;`
- replace the parenthesis with curly braces:

  `ArrTest<int> ar{};`

Comment: @MartinYork "*Put the better solution first*" - no, thank you. This is a Q&A site, and I prefer to answer the actual question that was asked first, before then offering alternatives afterwards. "*that is probably what he actually needs*" - I wouldn't call it a "need", since we don't know the actual requirements. "Should use" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure. But we can look at this as what is needed by the most people that would google a question like this (not the OP) and answer the question in a way that would help the most people. But either way works.

Answer (score 1):

This construction

```
info = ItemType[50];
```

is syntactically invalid. `ItemType` is a type as for example `int` because it is a type template parameter. So you have similarly to

```
info = int[50];
```

but the right side expression is not an object. It is a type specifier. So the compiler issues a compilation error.

Pay attention to that if you will write something like the following

```
template <class ItemType>
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest()
{
    ItemType a[50];
    info = a;
}
```

then the pointer `info` will have an invalid value because the local array `a` defined in the constructor will not be alive after exiting the constructor.

Comment: You explained what the error is, but you didn't explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **constructor initializer list** and `new`, as shown below:

```
template <class ItemType>
//----------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-->added this 
ArrTest<ItemType>::ArrTest(): info(new ItemType[50])
{
  
}
```

Also note that `ArrTest<int> ar();` declares a function named `ar` with the return type of `ArrTest<int>` and that takes no parameters. If your intention was to create an object of type `ArrTest<int>` then, you can replace it with:

```
ArrTest<int> ar{};
```

Also, don't forget to have a corresponding `delete[]` to free the allocated memory when no longer needed or use a `std::vector` so that you don't have to do manual memory management.

Answer (score 1):

Some answer suggested the use of `new` or, even better, `std::vector`. If the
number element is fixed and known at compile-time (e.g. `50`), you may consider a
`std::array`:

```
#include <array>

template <class ItemType>
class ArrTest {
   public:
   private:
    std::array<ItemType, 50> info;
};
```

or a C-style array:

```
template <class ItemType>
class ArrTest {
   public:
   private:
    ItemType info[50];
};
```

With these solutions, you don't need to implement destructor, copy/move
constructors and copy/move assignment operators. With respect to the
`std::vector` solution, you're not allocating memory on the heap, since array
`info` leaves on the stack. The downside is that the move operations will cost
you `O(sizeof(info) / sizeof(ItemType))` instead of `O(1)`.

Also, beware that:

```
int main() {
    ArrTest<int> ar0{};
    //           ^ This has all its elements initialized to int{} (i.e. (int)0)

    ArrTest<int> ar1;
    //           ^ This has all its elements uninitialized!!

    //ArrTest<int> ar2();
    //             ^ This declares a function!!
}
```