# Why does what appears to be a valid instantiation give a compile error?

Tags: c++

**Simple.h**

```
#pragma once
class Simple
{
public:
    Simple();
    void ShowIt();
};

**Simple.cpp**
#include "Simple.h"
#include <iostream>

Simple::Simple()
{
    std::cout << "in Simple Constructor" << std::endl;
}

void Simple::ShowIt()
{
    std::cout << "Showing It" << std::endl;
}
```

**Main in file CppTutor2023.cpp:**

```
#include "Simple.h"

int main()
{
   Simple obj1;
   Simple obj2();

   obj1.ShowIt();
   obj2.ShowIt();    // line 53
   ...
```

When I compile this I get the error:

```
Cpptutor2023.cpp(53,16): error C2228: left of '.ShowIt' must have class/struct/union
```

I expected line 52 to be the invalid one.
Also what is difference between lines 49 & 50? Again, I expected compiler to complain about line 49.

I have Visual Studio options set to use C++ version 17.

Comment: `Simple obj2();` is a function declaration.

Comment: [Is most vexing parse a formally defined concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937565/is-most-vexing-parse-a-formally-defined-concept)  Why would you expect line 49 to be a problem?

Comment: `Simple obj2()` => `Simple obj2{}`

Comment: Or `Simple obj2();` => `Simple obj2;`

Comment: Or if you want to get really fancy: `auto obj2 = Simple();`

Comment: Hint: look at the syntax coloring that was applied to your code automatically. Notice something different about the declarations of `obj1` and `obj2`?

Comment: Look up "most vexing parse".   The line `Simple obj2();` is interpreted as a declaration of a function named `obj2()` that accepts no arguments, and returns a `Simple`.  So your subsequent usage of `obj2` is invalid - since your code does things that can't be done to a function.   Options to fix include removing the `()` or (C++11 and later) changing the `()` to `{}`

Comment: "Again, I expected compiler to complain about line 49." **Why**? If you wrote `int x;`, would you be surprised that it worked, and wonder why you didn't have to write `int x();` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function declaration:

```cpp
Simple obj2();
```

If the constructor takes no arguments, simply omit the `()`

Comment: Many thanks to everyone that answered! The comment about syntax coloring was a nice clue! 
Sure enough - I looked up my old code and was surprised to see that all my objects were instantiated exactly as  you suggested. Guess I got wrapped around an axle a bit.
Or I've been working with PHP way too long! :D